# How to open any version of python using a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am having a couple of issues opening IDLE of python 3.5+ through my code.
The code opens CMD then closes again, most likely due to it being unable to open the .exe, this happens for both IDLE(Python3.6 64-bit.exe) and Python3.6 64-bit.exe

```
prompt = ("/")   

input = input (prompt)      

if input == ("html"): 
    print ("opening Notepad") 
    os.system('notepad.exe') 

elif input == ("python"): 
    print ("opening Python") 
    os.system('IDLE(Python3.6 32-bit.exe)')

else:
    print ("An error has occured")
```

The output is to open IDLE, however I haven't got any errors in shell, just with CMD being unable to open IDLE.

I apologize if this has already been answered in another question, but I haven't been able to find a suitable answer so far. Please feel free to add links to any possible answers to this problem.

Comment: I don't know what the command name is on your computer, but it seems highly unlikely that the `.exe` extension is *inside* the parentheses.

Comment: Tangentially, you should consider using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and for finding a syntax error in my code, much appreciated. I'll try to use subprocess instead of os.system and get back to you